# group in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am new to SQL and facing a trouble in grouping.I have a query which gives a table like

```
time                                          state1
____                                          ______
2015-04-01 00:00:00                             10
2015-04-01 00:00:00                             05
2015-04-01 00:00:00                             08
2015-04-01 01:00:00                             12
2015-04-01 01:00:00                             15
2015-04-01 01:00:00                             30
2015-04-01 02:00:00                             11
2015-04-01 02:00:00                             10
2015-04-01 02:00:00                             27
```

The query i am using is

```
SELECT time,state1 
FROM public.block_table 
where time >= '2015-04-01 00:00:00' 
  and time <= '2015-04-01 23:59:59' 
group by time, state1 
order by time;
```

Instead of this I want to have this grouped

```
    time                                          state1
    ____                                          ______
    2015-04-01 00:00:00                             23
    2015-04-01 00:00:00                             57
    2015-04-01 00:00:00                             48
```

I know I am missing a group function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SUM built in function to get result:

```
SELECT time,SUM(state1)
FROM Your_table 
WHERE --Your conditions---
GROUP BY time
```